# SimpleXML node parse Lyric Wikia REST API

Tags: php, xml, rest, rss, simplexml

Taken from the Lyrics Wikia REST api XML response http://api.wikia.com/wiki/LyricWiki_API/REST , how do I parse this? I wasn't able to find any examples of other people working with these nodes.

http://lyrics.wikia.com/api.php?func=getArtist&artist=Linkin_Park&fmt=xml

```
<getArtistResponse>
<artist>Linkin Park</artist>
<albums>
<album>Xero</album>
<year>1997</year>
<amazonLink>
http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/redirect?link_code=ur2&tag=wikia-20&camp=1789&creative=9325&path=external-search%3Fsearch-type=ss%26index=music%26keyword=Linkin%20Park%20Xero
</amazonLink>
<songs>
<item>Rhinestone</item>
<item>Reading My Eyes</item>
<item>Fuse</item>
<item>Stick N' Move</item>
</songs>
<album>Hybrid Theory</album>
<year>1999</year>
<amazonLink>
http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/redirect?link_code=ur2&tag=wikia-20&camp=1789&creative=9325&path=external-search%3Fsearch-type=ss%26index=music%26keyword=Linkin%20Park%20Hybrid%20Theory
</amazonLink>
<songs>
<item>Carousel</item>
<item>Technique</item>
<item>Step Up</item>
<item>And One</item>
<item>High Voltage (EP Version)</item>
<item>Part Of Me</item>
<item>High Voltage</item>
<item>Esaul (Underground EP)</item>
</songs>
<album>Hybrid Theory</album>
<year>2000</year>
<amazonLink>
http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/redirect?link_code=ur2&tag=wikia-20&camp=1789&creative=9325&path=external-search%3Fsearch-type=ss%26index=music%26keyword=Linkin%20Park%20Hybrid%20Theory
</amazonLink>
<songs>
<item>Papercut</item>
<item>One Step Closer</item>
<item>With You</item>
<item>Points Of Authority</item>
<item>Crawling</item>
<item>Runaway</item>
<item>By Myself</item>
<item>In The End</item>
<item>A Place For My Head</item>
<item>Forgotten</item>
<item>Cure For The Itch</item>
<item>Pushing Me Away</item>
<item>My December</item>
<item>High Voltage</item>
<item>Papercut</item>
<item>Papercut</item>
<item>Points Of Authority</item>
<item>A Place For My Head</item>
</songs>
```

I'd like for these to look like the following with links to each song node:

> Xero 1997: Rhinestone Reading My Eyes Fuse Stick N' Move
>
> Hybrid Theory 1999: Carousel Technique Step Up Etc..

I've been able to get the song->items with `

```
foreach ($xml->albums->songs as $entry){
     $item0 = $entry->item[0];
     $item1 = $entry->item[1]; 
     $item2 = $entry->item[2]; 
     $item3 = $entry->item[3];
     $item4 = $entry->item[4];
    etc
```

But I have been unsuccessful in grabbing each album and year beyond the first.

Thank you for the help. :)

Comment: The simpliest way, IMHO, in dealing with foreign arrays, objects, JSON and XML-like formats, is to first use `echo "<pre>"; print_r($myData);` and see it's internal structure and hierarchy in the browser. It helps a LOT in what you should be accessing and fetching and calling etc

Comment: If it's possible (and since we lack authorization to access your API session on that link), try to update your question with your fetched XML (I suppose it's `$xml`?) inside your var with this aforementioned line. You might not even need it for I'm sure you'll get what you need to do once you **see it**.

Comment: And if you have to also see data types and property visibility, use `var_dump` instead.